# Implementing generic DAO interface, return type of class implementing it must be cast to type T? why

Tags: java, generics, interface, dao

I am implementing a DAO for my first full stack java program and I am a bit confused when trying to implement this generic DAO interface. See below

```
public interface IDataAccessDAO<T> {

    List<T> selectAll();

    T selectSingle(int id);

    void insert(T t);

    void update(T t, String[] params);

    void delete(T t);

}

****************


@Override
    public List<T> selectAll() {

        List<Admin> allAdmins = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            //Create a connection to DB and prepare select statement
            Connection myConnect = this.getConnection()
            PreparedStatement ps = myConnect.prepareStatement(selectAllAdmin);

            //Store query result to build list of admins
            ResultSet queryResult = ps.executeQuery();

            while(queryResult.next()){

                int id = queryResult.getInt("adminId");
                String name = queryResult.getString("name");
                String email = queryResult.getString("email");
                String userName = queryResult.getString("userName");
                String password = queryResult.getString("password");


                Admin admin = new Admin(id, name, userName, password, email);

                allAdmins.add(admin);
                return (List<T>) allAdmins;
            }
```

My question is, why can I not just return allAmins instead of casting it to a generic. I thought the point of generics was to create flexibility in the return types of a class?

Comment: If I call the method expecting a LIst<String>` and you give me a List<Admin>` I will rightfully complain. How is your class implementing `IDataAccessDAO` defined, it should probably not have a `T` anymore but implement `IDataAccessDAO<Admin>`!?

Comment: What is the class signature for the class that's `implement`ing `IDataAccessDAO`, where this `selectAll` is defined?

Comment: What makes you think `T` is an `Admin`? If `T` is always an admin, what’s the point of it being generic?

Comment: This is not a [mcve], it is an incomplete snippet that has extraneous clutter but leaves out the important parts. To get a useful answer include something people can use to recreate the issue.  Since jdbc is not an issue that can be stubbed out.  How the type arguments are defined on the class is essential.